# Check Bitbucket login credentials inside shell script

Tags: git, bash, shell, terminal

I'm currently writing a shell/bash script to automate a workflow. This bash script can clone projects and create new repo's on Bitbucket, do composer install/update's and more of that stuff.

My first plan was to do this all over SSH, but there are some situations that I need HTTPS. For all thinks that go's over HTTPS I need to check the user credentials for Bitbucket first. The credentials consisting of a username and password.

Is this possible. If so, how?

Comment: Can you not just curl with -u and then check the returned error code (if any?)

Comment: Do you mean something like `curl -X GET -v -u "username:password" -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
    https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/$B_REPO_OWNER`. How can I put this inside a check like `if [ check ] ...`.

Comment: I guess you would need to grep against the data you expect to return on a successful login and then use the return code ($?) in your if statement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you suggested in comments, `curl` can do HTTP Basic Auth for you. For BitBucket, the response will be `401 Unauthorized` or `200 OK`, depending on the validity of username/password pair. You could test the output (or only headers) with `grep`, but a little bit more robust approach would be to use the [`-w`/`--write-out`](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#-w) option, combined with a `HEAD` request and `-s`ilenced output:

```
http_status=$(curl -X HEAD -s -w '%{http_code}' \
              -u "username:password" -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
              https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/$repo_owner)
```

Then, to test the status, you can use a simple conditional expression:

```
if [[ $http_status == 200 ]]; then
    echo "Credentials valid"
else
    if [[ $http_status == 401 ]]; then
        echo "Credentials INVALID"
    else
        echo "Unexpected HTTP status code: $http_status"
    fi
fi
```

Or, if you plan on testing multiple status codes, you can use the `case` command, for example:

```
case $http_status in
    200) echo "Credentials valid";;
    301|302) echo "API endpoint changed";;
    401) echo "Credentials INVALID";;
    5*) echo "BitBucket Internal server error";;
    *) echo "Unexpected HTTP status code: $http_status";;
esac
```

Comment: This is very useful!