# Using an "if" statement with curl in terminal?

Tags: linux, curl, command-line, terminal

I'm using this command to get the response code of a page using curl:

```
curl -s -o /dev/null -w "%{http_code}" 'https://www.example.com'
```

If the response code is `200`, then I want to delete a certain file on my computer.  If it isn't `200`, nothing should be done.

What's the easiest way to do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can store the result in a shell variable (via [command substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Command-Substitution)), and then test the value with a simple [`if` and `[[` command](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Conditional-Constructs). For example, in `bash`:

```
#!/bin/bash
code=$(curl -s -o /dev/null -w "%{http_code}" 'https://www.example.com')
if [[ $code == 200 ]]; then
    rm /path/to/file
    # other actions
fi
```

If all you want is a simple `rm`, you can shorten it to:

```
#!/bin/bash
[[ $code == 200 ]] && rm /path/to/file
```

In a generic POSIX shell, you'll have to use a less flexible `[` command and quote the variable:

```
#!/bin/sh
code=$(curl -s -o /dev/null -w "%{http_code}" 'https://www.example.com')
if [ "$code" = 200 ]; then
    rm /path/to/file
fi
```

---

Additionally, to test for a complete class of codes (e.g. `2xx`), you can use wildcards:

```
#!/bin/bash
[[ $code == 2* ]] && rm /path/to/file
```

and the `case` command (an example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45552609)).

Comment: As pointed out by @randomir on a deleted answer, the manual 2xx check is required (rather than checking the exit code) because `curl` will return success even on a 404.

Comment: I need this to process line by line comes from webpage, I can't store it into variable